# Pymongo on raspberry pi 3 wait too much to raise an error

Tags: python-2.7, pymongo, raspberry-pi3

I have an issue with pymongo on raspberry pi 3. The thing is when I run the script normally (I mean, I have internet connection and database connection, so there is not problem writing on database) I disconnect the wi-fi or ethernet from the Raspberry in order to get an error and handle it later but, when I disconnect the internet the script stops in the "insert_one" command of pymongo, like waiting until it gets internet connection again... so... the error raised several minutes later, like 25 minutes and that is not good for me, because I need to get the error inmediatly, so I can do some savings on a csv file.

```
from pymongo import MongoClient 
from pymongo import errors
from pymongo import client_options
from pymongo import settings

url     = 'emaweather.hopto.org'
port    = 27017
client_options.ClientOptions.server_selection_timeout = 1

try:        
    client = MongoClient(url, port)
    db = client['weather-mongo']
    print('Cliente: ' ,client)
    print('DB: ', db)
except errors.ConnectionFailure as e:
    print('Error: ', e)

def main():

  while True:

    try: 
        __readCSV()

        utc_now = pytz.utc.localize(datetime.datetime.utcnow())
        pst_now = utc_now.astimezone(pytz.timezone("America/Asuncion"))
        dateNowIsoFormat = pst_now.isoformat()
        print (dateNowIsoFormat)

        temperature,pressure,humidity = readBME280All()

        dbDataTemp = temperature
        print (dbDataTemp)

        dbDataHum = round(humidity,2)
        print (dbDataHum)

        dbDataPress = round(pressure,2)
        print (dbDataPress)

        dbData = {"date": dateNowIsoFormat, "temp": dbDataTemp, "hum": dbDataHum, "press": dbDataPress}
        db.data.insert_one(dbData)
        print('Writed on MongoDB')
        time.sleep(5)

    except errors.PyMongoError as error:
        print (error)

if __name__=="__main__":
   main()
```

Comment: Please post your code!

Comment: There is the code

Comment: Well... I've tryied with python 3.4 and it works. So... thanks for your time, guys